What is the fastest way to apply ALL default table properties to a pasted table in powerpoint?
I find myself frequently pasting a table into PowerPoint, then manually manipulating the style properties so that the table looks "nice" and fits with the template theme (i.e., matching the style for a table manually generated in PowerPoint).
Here is one way I do it:

Create a dummy table, to use as a reference for the default color palette & text properties.
Paste the table

Then the following steps are specific to my current template, and include

In the Table Design panel, check "Header Row"
In the Table Design panel, check "Banded Rows"
In the Table Design panel, apply the appropriate color palette
Change the font color of the header row to white (the header color is dark blue)
Change the font style to bold
Change the font size
In the Layout panel, apply "Normal" cell margins
In the Layout panel, adjust the text alignment

Another way, which maybe saves some time:

Create a 1x1 host table, which already has the table design (header row, banded rows, and colors)
Create a dummy table, to use as a reference for the default text properties
Paste my table content into the host table
Steps 6-10 from above

Either way takes a lot of clicks. I'd love to achieve the same result in (much) fewer clicks. BTW I'm using Office 365 in MacOS.

Try using the Paste Special option to paste data into an existing, already-formatted, empty, table. The example below applies to LibreOffice, but a similar option should be available in MS Office.


Select the block of data to be pasted.
Press CtrlCtrlV to open the Paste Special dialog.
Select what to paste, i.e., only data.
Paste into PowerPoint. where it should have the formatting of the existing PowerPoint table applied.

